# Response from Fetch() is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

There are two files: **RegistrationScreen.js** and **api.js**.

Inside **api.js** I'm running `fetch()` function:

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
    fetch(`http://${localIP}:${port}/api/userData`)
        .then(res => res.json()) 
        /* .then(json => console.warn('JSON: ' + json.userData[0].username))
        .catch(e => console.warn('ERROR: ' + e)) */
}
```

If comment back the second `.then()` I'm able to see **username** from response.

I'm importing this function into **RegistrationScreen.js**:

```
import { fetchAllUsers } from '../../constants/api';

export default class RegistrationScreen extends Component{

    static defaultProps = {
        fetchAllUsers
    }

    onCreateButtonPress = async () => {
        ...
        let usernameValidation = await this.checkUsernameUniqueness();
        ...
    }

    checkUsernameUniqueness = async () => {
        const data = await this.props.fetchAllUsers();
        console.warn('user = ' + data)
    }
    ...

}
```

And as an outcome I get in the console **user = undefined**.
Why I can see the data inside **api.js** but not in **RegistrationScreen.js**?

**UPDATE_1**

If do `console.warn(this.props.fetchAllUsers)` inside **RegistrationScreen.js** I see the function code so the function is visible.

Comment: Are you returning the response from the fetch function? You might want to try returning res.json() inside the then.

Comment: you need to `return` the promise  i.e ``export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
    return fetch(`http://${localIP}:${port}/api/userData`) ..... }``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `fetchAllUsers` you aren't return anything from it, that is why you are getting `undefined`. A function with no `return` returns undefined.

This returns `undefined`

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
    fetch(`http://${localIP}:${port}/api/userData`)
        .then(res => res.json()) 
        /* .then(json => console.warn('JSON: ' + json.userData[0].username))
        .catch(e => console.warn('ERROR: ' + e)) */
}
```

This returns a promise

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
    // added return 
    return fetch(`http://${localIP}:${port}/api/userData`)
        .then(res => res.json())
}
```

You forgot to return the promise from `fetch`